# cordova/phonegap - splashscreen showed without adding any plugin on windows phone 8

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am porting a project from android to windows phone 8 and I am using cordova/phonegap.

I did not add any plugin so far but I already have a splashscreen displayed for some seconds.

There is nothing related to it in my **config.xml**

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
    <access origin="*"/>
</widget>
```

neither in my **properties/AppManifest.xml**

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">  
  <Deployment.Parts>
  </Deployment.Parts>
</Deployment>
```

I created a cordova project with VS 2012 Express as below

[image]

- Why does it happen?

Comment: Doesn't every mobile application has a splash screen?

Comment: well, no not every mobile app of the world, neither every cordova app there is a plugin to add for it http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen

Comment: I am developing iOS apps with Cordova. EVERY iOS App has a splash screen this is mandatory. I don't know about Windows Mobile though. What does Windows Mobile display while loading if not the splash screen? Give me one example of an windows mobile app that has no splash screen.
The plugin is for manually showing or hide... you know that right? It will be done automatically if there is no plugin.

Comment: on my wp there a number of them like: (in alfaphetic order) alarm-calculator-calendar ... nokia camera; they are system app anyway. I just took this smartphone and I did not download many of them. when you do an helloworld it does use a "loading ..."; not even on android is mandatory

Comment: I just asked on wpexchange to know that http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/6037/is-splash-screen-mandatory-on-windows-phone-apps